# sorting columns in a .csv file

Tags: python, sorting, csv, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a .csv file which I want to sort.

I currently have two columns, 'Name' and 'Score'.

I'd like to use SQLite to sort these two columns in Python 3. I want to sort 'Name' by alphabetical order and 'Score' by score highest to lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use sqlite3 to sort it.

You can use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) or [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with a key function: `lambda row: (row[0], -int(row[1])))` after loading the csv file as a list.